# capture data from array as where

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a school student data, the school consists of several classes such as class A, Class B and class C and have grade as well. however I would like to retrieve student and class data based on the grade of the varibale. I tried to do it but still failed the data did not appear.

Example:

tb_class

```
 ID   |  id_class | grade | 
 ---- | --------- |-------|
 1    |    A      |   1   |
 2    |    B      |   2   |
 3    |    C      |   1   |
 4    |    D      |   3   |
___________________________
```

tb_user

```
 ID   |  id_class | id_user  |
 ---- | --------- | -------- |
 1    |    A      |    002   |  
 2    |    B      |    008   |  
 3    |    B      |    005   |  
 4    |    A      |    006   |
 5    |    C      |    007   |
 6    |    C      |    003   |
 7    |    D      |    001   |   
______________________________

$grade= 1;

$query_grade = $this->db->select('id_class')
                    ->from('tb_class')
                    ->where('grade', $grade)
                    ->get()->result();

$data = array($query_grade);
$query_user = $this->db->select('id_user')
                       ->from('tb_user')
                       ->where_in('id_class', $data)
                       ->get()->result();
return $query_user;
```

which I expect to appear data 002, 006, 007, 003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** You giving data to where_in in wrong condition you should prepare your result to right format like simple array.

```
$query_grade = $this->db->select('id_class')
                    ->from('tb_class')
                    ->where('grade', $grade)
                    ->get()->result_array();

    foreach ($query_grade as $value)
    {
        $ids[] = $value['id_class'];
    }


$query_user = $this->db->select('id_user')
                       ->from('tb_user')
                       ->where_in('id_class', $ids)
                       ->get()->result();
return $query_user;
```

$query_user will holds your data.

**Second:** if above code looks complex you can use below code.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_user FROM tb_user WHERE id_class IN(SELECT id_class FROM tb_class WHERE grade = '{$grade}')");
$data = $query->result();
```

You will get appropriate result.

Sometimes you cant create complex queries with query builder.

Comment: thanks vikrant, yes this is what i expected. but what if otherwise grade 1 is not my search, I try `-> where_in ('id_class <>', $ ids)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
    $grade = 1;
    $this->db->select('id_class');
    $this->db->from('tb_class');
    $this->db->join('tb_user', 'tb_class.id_class = tb_user.id_class',array('id_user'));
    $this->db->where('grade', $grade);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```